# Is Microsoft stopped support for ashx handlers?

Tags: asp.net, ashx

Can i use ashx handlers or not?recently one of my friend told that Microsoft stopped supporting ashx handlers and suggested to use asmx or wcf.

I have searched over web for this. i am not able to finalize whether it actually does it or not.

So any one please tell me whether Microsoft support for ashx or not.?.

Comment: I've got an ASP.NET 2.0 site that's still working with ASHX handlers...so it may depend on the version of the framework you're running if anything. I'd be surprised for Microsoft to suddenly stop supporting something without documenting it...

Comment: @Tim we are working on .net framework 4.0 currently.is it better to use ashx ?

Comment: _"told that Microsoft stopped supporting ashx handlers and suggested to use asmx or wcf"_ - handlers and webservices serve an entirely different purpose, while it may be able to use the one for the other, I think your friend should either back his claims with sources or stop rambling. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, support for HTTP Handlers (.ashx, both IIS registered and file endpoints) are still fully supported in ASP.NET 4.5.

I believe your friend was misinformed or confused.

As for your friend's recommendation about using .asmx or WCF in place of HTTP Handlers is misguided advice, as the purpose of the two technologies (HTTP Handlers vs. web services) are very different.

If anything, the recommendation should be to not use .asmx web services anymore in favor of WCF, ASP.NET Web API or a REST-based service.

For proof of support, you need to look no further than the `Add New Item` dialog inside Visual Studio 2012:

[image]

> Note: The `ASP.NET Handler` option highlighted.

Comment: @karl-thanks for the info

Comment: The fact that there is an item template installed with Visual Studio 2012 that is called "ASP.NET Handler" doesn't say _anything_ about whether Microsoft still supports handlers in ASP.NET (if they didn't support ASP.NET handlers anymore tomorrow, will the item still be in your Visual Studio?). People often seem to not understand what "support" means. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster - I disagree with your statement, because the latest released version of ASP.NET (ASP.NET 4.5) has support. Without an update to the .NET Framework, removal of support for .ashx handlers would be difficult to happen overnight.

Comment: Two items above that handler is "JavaScript File". Does Microsoft support JavaScript files? All I'm saying is this list is no proof of _"Microsoft supports X"_. :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Microsoft has never announced to stop supporting the .NET framework including webforms. ASHX files are an essential tool to accomplisch certain activities

I use it mainly for downloading files from the website using a bitstream.

To exchange information (text, XML, Json) a webmethod is preferred. Wether that resides in de aspx code behind or a seperate ASMX file is of no concern.